# Retrofit surrogate key in table with natural key in MySql?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, surrogate-key, natural-key

Assume a table that uses a natural key and has a number of existing rows. What would be the easiest way to retrofit a surrogate key column and populate it with unique values using MySql?

I.e. transform

```
table employees
(
    social_security_no varchar(20),
    ...
    constraint emp_pk primary key (social_security_no)
);
```

to

```
table employees
(
    id int,
    social_security_no varchar(20),
    ...
    constraint emp_pk primary key (id)
);
```

and fill the new id column with valid id:s.

Thanks /Erik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
ALTER TABLE employees DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE employees ADD (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Optionally you'll (probably) want to do this:

```
CREATE INDEX employees_ssn ON employees (social_security_no);
```

and for any referencing tables:

```
ALTER TABLE blah ADD (employees_fk INT);
UPDATE blah b SET employees_fk = (SELECT id FROM employees WHERE social_security_no = b.ssn);
ALTER TABLE blah DROP (ssn);
```